# What wordpress plugin prevent sharing of contact information amongst users?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Any wordpress plugin to robustly detect and prevent the sharing of contact details (email address and phone number) in user-generated content globally?

For a wordpress website like Fiverr. com

Unfortunately, Google cannot answer this question.